# string split and store value in TCL

Tags: tcl

I have a function which returns me string into following way

```
% set b [le::splitIntoBoxes $m1_drw -type maxX]
{1.154 0.068 1.222 0.518} {1.154 0.518 1.370 0.562}
```

I would like split string and store values in x1 y1 x2 y2. I have tried all option
    but not able to fix issue

```
% puts [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $b]
\{1.154 0.068 1.222 0.518\} \{1.154 0.518 1.370 0.562\}
```

I would like to ignore "\" so I can store values in x1 y1 x2 y2.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: split  {} but did not work

Comment: Paste how did you do it.

Comment: And in tcl you cannot do this: `set b {1.154 0.068 1.222 0.518} {1.154 0.518 1.370 0.562}` It should be: `set var_name var_value`

Comment: puts [split $b {}] output : \{ 1 . 1 5 4 { } 0 . 0 6 8 { } 1 . 2 2 2 { } 0 . 5 1 8 \} { } \{ 1 . 1 5 4 { } 0 . 5 1 8 { } 1 . 3 7 0 { } 0 . 5 6 2 \}

Comment: Yes One function is returning this value. I use sudo code here.. Main code is : set b [le::splitIntoBoxes $m1_drw -type maxX]

Comment: So it's returning list of lists. I've added an answer that may help you

Comment: List of box descriptors, where each box descriptor is a four-item list that describes (guessing…) the bounding box? Use `foreach` and `lassign`…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have a string as returned and have to parse it as al list of lists.

So for example:

```
foreach token $b {
    foreach {x1 y1 x2 y2} $token {break;}
    puts "x1 $x1 y1 $y2 x2 $x2 y2 $y2"
}
```

The first *foreach* 'split' the string in chunks on spaces.

Than you have chunks like:

> {1.154 0.068 1.222 0.518}

That is a list itself, in the second loop you're going to assign each element of this list to your designed variables.

Comment: In Tcl 8.5 or later, you can also assign using `lassign $token x1 y1 x2 y2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
% proc mysplit d {
    concat {*}$d
}
% set b {{1.154 0.068 1.222 0.518} {1.154 0.518 1.370 0.562}}
{1.154 0.068 1.222 0.518} {1.154 0.518 1.370 0.562}
% mysplit [mysplit $b]
1.154 0.068 1.222 0.518 1.154 0.518 1.370 0.562
```